# dynamically create sortable list and perform action on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am dynamically creating a sortable list. However the .on('dblclick') action is not working for the newly created list items. It only works for the static list.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
```

refresh also doesnot seems to work.
Here's my full code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
            $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
        });
        var i = 10;
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#btn_createList').click(function() {    
                $('.ul_current').append('<li id="foo_' + i + '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' + i);
                i++;
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
            });
        }); 
        $("#sortable li").on('dblclick',function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
}); 
    </script>

</head>
<body>

 <ul id="sortable" class="ul_current">
    <li id="foo_1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li id="foo_2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li id="foo_3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>

</ul>

 <button id="btn_createList">add</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're attaching an event to an element that isn't ready to receive that event. You should attach the event to a parent element, then you can filter for `#sortable li`. This way it doesn't matter when your click able element gets added, it will work. This is called event delegation. You're delegating the task of handling the event to another element.

And your JS:

```
$("#sortable").on("dbclick", "li", function() {
    alert('it works!');
});
```

Also when doing this, don't attach it to a parent that's too high up the tree. You want to attach it to the nearest possible parent element (in this case `#sortable`). We don't need to have a click event on something like `document` because it's a good idea to be specific of which elements will get this event. Attaching it to `document` will mean that any element, that has `li`, will be click able and respond to the same code. If you want to have different functionality in different buttons, you can't, because they're all responding to the same code attached to `document`.

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation to have the event bound for the dynamically created `li`s

```
   $("#sortable").on('dblclick','li', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf6NW/)**

Or the same way you are doing `$( "#sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );` after the element has been added, bind the event for the added element like this:

```
$('#btn_createList').click(function () {

         var $li = $('<li/>', {
             id: 'foo_' + i,
                 'class': 'ui-state-default'
         }).on('dblclick', handleDblClick).append($('<span/>', {
             'class': 'ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'
         })).append(i);

         $('.ul_current').append($li);
         i++;
         $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
     });

     $("#sortable li").on('dblclick', handleDblClick);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BL66S/)**

Comment: @Sushil you are welcome... If this works please do remember to mark one of the answers you got as you feel appropriate.